# Convert BMP to video in a given frame rate in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate

I am trying to encode several BMPs\JPEG into a movie file using:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i a%d.jpg output.mpg
```

The thing is that I want the frame rate of the movie to be 10, and it seems to be 25 (as a default I guess). How can I tell it what framerate to use?

I am using Windows 7, 64-bit (DELL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [FFmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html). The framerate is specified with `-r`.

As an [example for image-to-video conversion](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Examples-6), they mention:

> Use ffmpeg for creating a video from the images in the file sequence
>   ‘img-001.jpeg’, ‘img-002.jpeg’, ..., assuming an input frame rate of
>   10 frames per second:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i 'img-%03d.jpeg' -r 10 out.mkv
> ```

Note that normally, the usage of `-f image2` isn't necessary. Also, the default settings used to convert to `.mpg` files may result in low quality. If you can afford it, try using x264 and MP4 container instead:

```
ffmpeg -i a%d.jpg -r 10 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 21 output.mp4
```

Vary the `-crf` parameter for quality, where less means better quality and more means worse quality. Sane values could be anything from 18 to 26, with the default set at 23.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So probably better specifying `-r 10 -i …` then for the above use case?